# admob is not showing because "maybe RelativeLayout"

Tags: android, admob

Hello i have already made the app. but My admob ads are working fine with splash activitvity. But wont show on my activity_main. its showing fine but it seems like there is no space left too show ads because of RelativeLayout.

whats is wrong please help.

**here is XML code.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- suppress ALL -->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
android:background="@drawable/item_select"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<!-- ListRow Left sied Thumbnail image -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:background="#fbf4ff"
    android:padding="10dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_image"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imageViewDescription"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_24" />

</LinearLayout>
<!-- Title Of Song -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:text="@string/RihannaLove"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/rating"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_rating" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_above="@layout/activity_main"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:ignoreGravity="@drawable/background_item"
    android:visibility="visible" >

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/libs/com.google.ads"
        android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:ignoreGravity="@drawable/item_select"
        app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-2235803990161195/8451367464" >
    </com.google.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

**and here is  code were admob is on** 

private void setRingstone(int id, String path, String RingstoneName, String mode) 
        throws NotFoundException, IllegalArgumentException, IOException,         IllegalAccessException {

    //Move ringtone to sdcard
    moveRingtoneToSDcard(id, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" +         folder_name_in_sdcard + "/" + path + ".mp3");
    // Music file will choose to set new Ringtone
    String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + folder_name_in_sdcard + "/" + path + ".mp3";
    Log.i("TAG", filepath);
    File ringtoneFile = new File(filepath);

    ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
    content.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, ringtoneFile.getAbsolutePath());
    content.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, RingstoneName);
    content.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, 215454);
    content.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/*");
    content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "");
    content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION, 230);
    content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

    // Set as Ringtone
    if (mode.equals(Ringtone))
        content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
    else
        content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, false);

    // Set as Notification
    if (mode.equals(Notification))
        content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
    else
        content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);

    // Set as Alarm
    if (mode.equals(Alarm))
        content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
    else
        content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
    adView =  (AdView)findViewById(R.id.ad);
    adView.setTag("adView");
    adView.refreshDrawableState();
    adView.setVisibility(AdView.VISIBLE);
    adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.ad);
    AdView.LayoutParams adViewParams = new AdView.LayoutParams(
        AdView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
        AdView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    //the next line is the key to putting it on the bottom
    adViewParams.addRule(AdView.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

    ViewGroup relativeLayout = null;
    relativeLayout.addView(adView, adViewParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems here.

1) You are defining you AdView in XML but then attempting to add it a second time to your RelativeLayout in code. NB The code addition will fail with the NullPointerException because RelativeLayout is null. Just define your AdView in XML.

2) The definition of the position of your RelativeLayout in XML specifies an invalid layout_above. You need to refer to a layout element that exists within the current layout. If you want your ad to display above the thumbnail then I suggest something like:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_above="@id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:ignoreGravity="@drawable/background_item"
    android:visibility="visible" >

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/libs/com.google.ads"
        android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:ignoreGravity="@drawable/item_select"
        app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-2235803990161195/8451367464" >
    </com.google.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

3) You have specified loadOnCreate in your XML, but you are also loading an ad via code. Choose one.